# setting default index dates in elasticsearch 2.1

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

I want to create an index in elasticsearch 2.1 with a default date/time field.  The documentation for 2.1 states that _timestamp is deprecated in 2.0 and to use the date type instead

So My question is what is the proper way to create an index with a default timestamp/date for all new records?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html#mapping-timestamp-field) clearly says to create a new date field and set its value explicitly when indexing a document. This is just like indexing any other field.

> The _timestamp field is deprecated. Instead, use a normal date field
>   and set its value explicitly.

Comment: so there is no way to create a default date/timestamp in an index anymore?

Comment: Yes, that's what the docs say. `_timestamp` is only deprecated. It is not removed. So you can use it while it lasts but do not depend on it as a long term solution if you plan to keep Elasticsearch always updated to the latest version.